# Weird noise coming from laptop (probably the motherboard)

Tags: motherboard, noise

**TL;DR:** Two types of noises are coming from my laptop - a buzzing noise and a zipping noise. I checked another laptop for the noises and figured out that the "buzzing" noise is (probably) common to all laptops. But I can't figure out why the "zipping" noise is coming.

---

**Edit:** I opened HWMonitor and checked the CPU currents. The "zipping" noise has no relation to the (CPU) current. Also, I noticed that it can be heard in GPU intensive tasks. So, the GPU circuit is having a problem (probably).

---

**Note:** It isn't coil whine.

---

I have noticed an annoying **zipping** noise coming from my laptop. I thought that it was the fans at first, then the hard drives, but it turns out it seems to be coming from the motherboard, though I'm not sure.

I've heard the noise when scrolling in the Task View (as soon as I stop scrolling, the noise stops), using the selection tool and crop tool in Photoshop, and when scrolling to a particular section (exactly when it is in the center of the screen) of [this page](https://about.google/stories/verificado19s/). It might be because of the CPU drawing a high current.

I noticed it when I was using a mouse. So, I tried doing the above mentioned tasks with the trackpad, and the noise was still there. I tried unplugging the mouse, unplugging the barrel adapter, but the noise still came. So, I put my head above the keyboard and moved it to the place where the intensity of the noise is the highest, which turned out to be somewhere around the ‘G’ key (at a distance of about one-third of the width of the laptop from the left edge), right where my RAM is (2x4GB). The laptop is ~9 months old.

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks.

---

**Laptop**:

Acer Aspire 3

Ryzen 5 2500u

Vega 8 iGPU

2x 4GB (2400MHz) DDR4 memory (6.9 GB usable, 1.1 GB reserved for iGPU because there's no VRAM (or GDDR Memory))

1TB Seagate HDD

Comment: What is the model of the laptop?

Comment: @spike_66 added that to the question

Comment: As you see on this [page](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/474482/am-i-the-only-one-with-a-noisy-fan-on-swift-3) you're not the only one with this problem. You should contact the Acer [Technical Support](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/service-contact)

Comment: @spike_66 I'm not talking about the fan noise, it can hardly be heard. That page mentioned "whistling" noise, but I'm talking about a weird electrical noise along with a "zipping" noise under GPU intensive tasks. I'll post this on the Acer Community Forum too. Btw, Acer doesn't offer on-site support and their service center is a bit far away from where I live. Their chat support link is also broken in my country,. Their community forum is the only way to get help.